# What's the efficient way to feed elements from Iterator (from tf.data.Dataset) into TensorFlow model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using TensrFlow's new API for importing data via `tf.data.Dataset` and iterators. It is working fine, but I'm not sure if what I do is efficient.

What I'm doing at the moment is evaluating an iterator's `get_next()` method, which gives me a bunch of elements like the actual image, its label, filename, etc. I then feed the image into my model using the `feed_dict`.

I know that `feed_dict` is very slow, so am I losing benefits of `Dataset` and Iterators and having serialised dataset in `TFRecord`s by evaluating the entries and feeding them into the graph via `feed_dict`? I haven't found any examples in TF's documentation which shows how one's expected to use Iterator's `get_next()` to feed elements into the model. Is it better to unpack `get_next()` and use the result directly in my graph?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is advisable to use the tensors returned by `get_next()` directly in your graph. Perhaps you missed the [Programmer's Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_values_from_an_iterator) on the `tf.data` API.

You may also find the [performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/performance/datasets_performance) instructive.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In that case would there be a way to run the model without getting the next batch? It's common to evaluate accuracy on the same training batch every now and then with different model parameters than optimization step (for instance with dropout keep_prob set to 1). How would I do that if I'm not feeding images in two steps using feed_dict ?

Comment: Not to necromance this thread, but the documentation above in the tf.data programmer's guide link - is it saying that we should replace existing tf.placholders with the iterator.get_next() outputs instead, if the get_next() results would normally be inserted into the placeholders via feed_dict? Am I understanding that correctly?